# Order of execution of couchDb queries

Tags: couchdb

In querying couchDb views what is the order of execution of queries.For instance if I have these query parameters in the url

```
someurl?reduce=false&descending=true&startkey="something"
```

in what order will they be executed.

The main problem that I am encountering is with *descending= true*.When I don't pass that parameter I am able to paginate just fine however if I pass *descending = true* the paging breaks completely.I am guessing this has something to do with the order of execution of queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no order, the queries are declarative. But, for the case of `descending=true`, you have to reverse startkey and endkey values. See [the docs](https://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/design.html#get-db-design-design-doc-view-view-name) for more.